# Orika object mapping

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I am trying to map String to UUID with orika but I get the following error:

sourceType = java.lang.String
destinationType = java.util.UUID
Error occurred: No converter registered for conversion from String to UUID, nor any ObjectFactory which can generate UUID from String

```java
public class SourceType {
    private String firstId;

  //setters getters
}

public class DestinationType {
    private UUID firstId;
  //setters getters
}

mapperFactory.classMap(SourceType.class, DestinationType.class)
                .byDefault()
                .customize(new MyCustomMapper())
                .register();

private final class MyCustomMapper extends CustomMapper<SourceType, DestinationType> {
        @Override
        public void mapAtoB(final SourceType sourceType, final DestinationType destinationType, final MappingContext context) {
             destinationType.setFirstId(UUID.fromString(sourceType.getFirstId()));
    }
}
```